# Printing underscores for corresponding amount of letters

Tags: python

I'm trying to take the answer of the hangman, and have it print the same amount of underscores as the answer of the hangman is long. I have tried putting in

```
for letters in range(wordChoice):

        print("_")
```

however, that only prints one underscore on the next line. I have also tried

```
print("_", * wordChoice)
```

and that told me that wordChoice is not defined. Below is the original code without my attempts in it.

```
def WordChoice():

    wordChoice = input("Please Enter The Answer Of Choice:\n>>> ")
    
    print("You Entered:\n>>> ", wordChoice)
    print(list(wordChoice))
    
    playerConfirmation = int(input("If Correct, Enter 1\nIf Not Correct, Enter 2:\n>>> "))

    correct = 1

    if playerConfirmation == correct:

        print("Answer Has Been Stored! Please Pass Keyboard To Player 1!")

    else:

        WordChoice()
```

Comment: apologies @PranavHosangadi I edited my post

Comment: solved:  the solution that I found by asking in discord is
```for letter in wordChoice:

        print('_ ', end='')```